# Bad Access error in variable have set and get inside extension

Tags: ios, swift

When use this variable show bad access 
what is problem with that?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the image with your actual code, copied and pasted into the question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (btw, your nickname is very courageous, because as a *professional* you are supposed to see the issue instantly ;-) ). First of all please post text / code rather than an image. Secondly, you code is creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Lookup "infinite recursion".

Answer (score 0):

In your setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, you assign `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property. Which calls the setter for `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler`, which assigns `newValue` to the `pullToRefreshCompletionHandler` property.

The problem at this point should be clear. ;-)

Comment: This "answer" is cute but it isn't an answer. A good answer would also explain how to solve the problem.

Comment: To solve the problem... don't call the setter from inside the setter? I'm not sure how much needs to be said, really.